# Don't Understand the concept of the pushViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Can Anyone explain me the concept of Pushing and Popping Stack Items in `UINavigationController`.I only know the meaning of the `Push` and `Pop` that used in stack opreation in Data Structure but Don't know how it work in `UINavigationController`.Please also explain the the following functions of it.

```
pushViewController:animated:

- popViewControllerAnimated:

- popToRootViewControllerAnimated:

- popToViewController:animated:

interactivePopGestureRecognizer
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the same concept as a stack in a data structure really, except you can only view whats on the top (ie the top viewcontroller in your navigation stack)

so pushing a viewcontroller means its going on top of the stack (animates coming in from the right) popping a viewcontroller will take a viewcontroller off the top (which is the current one you are looking at) so it will animate off the right of the screen, showing the viewcontroller that was underneath the top one

`popToRootViewController` is effectively just popping until you hit the very last viewcontroller in your navigation stack

`popToViewController` pops until a particular viewcontroller is on the top

Hope thats all the clarification you need